# MassTransit Preserve Messages Sent While RabbitMQ Going Down

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit 3.5 against RabbitMQ.  I have an F5 load balancer acting as a failover between 2 RabbitMQ nodes.  If I take down the primary node, but keep sending messages via MassTransit during the downtime, any messages sent while RabbitMQ is going down are lost before the F5 can fail over to the secondary node.  How can I ensure that messages won't be lost?

Is this an F5 problem?  If so, what is the best way to ensure immediate failover to the secondary node?  I've seen Chris Patterson's comment [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/masstransit-discuss/94tsugp8fLk): "F5 does AMQP-level health monitoring".  But I'm being told by our network security folks who manage the F5 that the F5 knows nothing about AMQP.  Are we missing some kind of F5 update or plugin or something that enables awareness of AMQP?  Right now, our F5 monitor is doing an HTTPS hit to the individual RabbitMQ nodes like: https://the_ip_of_the_node:15671/api/.  And there's an interval of 3 seconds with a 10 second timeout.  I don't think this is right based on Chris Patterson's comment.

Our existing monitor does work eventually, but any messages sent before the failover happens are just lost completely.  So I have a 13-second window of doom where these messages just evaporate.

I'm not seeing an AMQP F5 monitor type [here](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm_configuration_guide_10_0_0/ltm_appendixa_monitor_types.html), so how can F5 failover based on AMQP?  [This post](http://grokbase.com/t/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-discuss/135nqtptdp/f5-load-balancer-pool-management) talks about writing a custom binary in C to give to the F5 to use for this kind of monitoring - is that the solution?  Seems hard.

Comment: Is this perhaps a Server Fault sort of problem???

Comment: I don't know whether this belongs on stackoverflow or serverfault to be honest.  I thought this might perhaps involve a code-based solution, but it may not.

Comment: Are you awaiting the call to `Publish` and properly retrying if an exception is thrown?

Comment: I found a NuGet package Polly.Net40Async that will retry async calls, and if I use it to wrap calls to bus.Publish, bus.Send and bus.Request, etc. it looks like it will mitigate these lost messages.

Comment: You can also use the built-in MassTransit retry policy to retry your methods. I'll see if I can muster an answer for you.